# /dev/ttyUSB0 plug detection

Tags: usb, sh

I need to make a script (/bin/sh) to detect when a new /dev/ttyUSB* device is plugged and when it's disconnected.
I can't use uevent because they aren't supported on my platform, I can only start a service on boot that wait for /dev/ttyUSB* appears.

How can i made that?

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Beagleboard running Android. Also "on device-added-/dev/ttyUSBx" in init.rc is not working.